# How to regexp_contains for a pattern text

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm still newbie to Bigquery.
I'm trying to get a data, if a field there is a string like:

> 

```
> /a/arrow
> /b/bow
> /c/cheese
> /d/dog
> /e/edward
> /f/fruit
> ....
> /z/zebra
```

I've written:

```
WHEN
REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(page_name),'/|^/a/|^/b/|^/c/|^/d/|^/e/|^/f/|^/g/|^/h/|^/i/|/^j/|^/k/|^/l/|^/m/|^/n/|^/o/|^/p|^/q/|^/r/|^/s/|^/t/|^/u/|^/v/|^/w/|^/x/|^/y/|^/z/') then 'library'
```

But it's still not working well, mixed with values other than those in the pattern. Can I get the correct value? thank you

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe `WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(page_name),'^/[a-z]/[a-z]+$')`?

Comment: thank you, sir! it works with REGEXP_CONTAINS(entrance_page_name,'^/[a-z]/+')

Comment: The last `+` is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_CONTAINS(entrance_page_name,'^/[a-z]/')
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `/` - a `/` char.